# How can I give permissions to a user to be able to use the "Performance" monitor in W2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, permissions

I have a user that needs to be able to access the Performance counters tool in one of my servers, but I can't make him an admin.

Is there a way to grant him this permission?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, add him to the Performance Monitors users group on that machine.  Use the computer management snap in, navigate to local users and groups, groups, and add him there.